# Querying a webserver as if request came from a certain remote IP?

Tags: web-server, ip, apache-2.4, debugging

I am having trouble with my Apache web server configuration since a number of remote clients receive 404s, while the majority of clients (me, locally, included) do not have any trouble (status 200). Hence, for the sake of debugging, I'd like to send test queries (via curl) to the web server *as if* the request came from a certain remote IP and examine the responses.

Is this even possible? I understand that [IP spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing) is not a desirable feature for regular Internet packages, but is there a way to achieve something similar locally when I am in full control of my web server?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can the downvoter please kindly elaborate why she/he deems this question off-topic or not well formulated?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible.

I'd recommend renting a cheap VPS in your target client area and then proxying your test requests through that server.

That said, if you examine your logs, you will see the exact links requested when clients receive the 404 errors. Then you'll have a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your kind advise. Actually, our logs do not answer why Apache sends a 404 for one specific IP and 200 for everyone else. Hence, I am looking for a way to reproduce that error. I see the 404 happen in the logs, but there is no reason for it to happen. Other IPs querying the same resource do get a 200, so a rented VPS will most likely not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://geopeeker.com/,  http://www.webpagetest.org  to see how it appears from different locations of the world.

Comment: Thanks for the links. These are interesting tools, but I was looking more for a method of verifying the system for a specific IP other than repeatedly asking the client to please try again.